# using BitmapSource as Image source in WPF

Tags: wpf, event-handling, bitmap, freeze, bitmapsource

I'm trying to update an Image (_browserScreenshot below) object in XAML by changing the source image every time an event determines the source needs updating.  Right now I have this:

```
public BitmapSource GetScreen()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(app.Browser.ClientRectangle.Width, app.Browser.ClientRectangle.Height);
    app.Browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, app.Browser.Bounds);

    BitmapSource bitmapSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    bitmapSource.Freeze();

    bitmap.Dispose();
    bitmap = null;
    return bitmapSource;
}
```

Then I have an event handler as shown:

```
app.BitmapSource.Changed += new EventHandler(BitmapSource_Changed);

void BitmapSource_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window1._browserScreenshot.Source = app.GetScreen();
}
```

Now whenever this event fires a new screenshot is taken and the source of the Image (called _browserScreenshot here) control should be updated.  I keep getting an error about changing the IsFrozen propery, but I can't figure out how to change this correctly and have this work the way I want it to.  Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Could you add some details about the error you get?  Nothing is jumping out at me as horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelyhood you *want* to Freeze the object. The problem you are having is that you want to create a completely new BitmapSource every time and let the garbage collector dispose of the old image.

Answer (score 0):

The following line turned out to be my problem:

bitmapSource.Freeze();